# Display text message after clicking on menu button in telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

1. Add a fourth category "About"
2. Clicking on "About" will send a text message e.g. "Operating since 1999"

Here is the code snippet:

```py
def main_menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Bubble Tea', callback_data='m1')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Waffle', callback_data='m2')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Otah', callback_data='m3')]]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

[image]

```py
# Add command handler to dispatcher
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='m1'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_menu, pattern='m2'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(third_menu,pattern='m3'))
```

I have been trying with different ways of displaying text as shown below but not too sure how to piece them together with the dispatcher

```py
bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="About xxxxx details ")   
update.message.reply_text("About xxxx details ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add a fourth category "About"

```py
def main_menu_keyboard():
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Bubble Tea', callback_data='m1')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Waffle', callback_data='m2')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('Otah', callback_data='m3')],
                  [InlineKeyboardButton('About', callback_data='m4')]]  # new button
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

> Clicking on "About" will send a text message e.g. "Operating since 1999"

```py
def about_message(bot, update):  # handler for "About" button
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.callback_query.from_user.id, text="Operating since 1999")  

# ... other existing code

# Add command handler to dispatcher
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(main_menu, pattern='main'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(first_menu, pattern='m1'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(second_menu, pattern='m2'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(third_menu, pattern='m3'))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(about_message, pattern='m4'))  # add handler for "About" button

# ... other existing code
```